# SharePoint Modal Survey close redirect to another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modal-dialog, redirect

I am trying to display a modal survey question from the home page of my site.  I have that working, what I am looking for is how to upon click of the finish button redirect to a tableau site.  I do not want go to a thank you page just back to the other site.

Here is my code:

```
<input onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: '../sites/STS020170908232517/quota/Lists/2017%20Quota%20Acknowledgement/NewForm.aspx?Source=https://www.reporting-analytics.philips.com/#/signin?redirect=%2Fsite%2FPhilipsHealthcareNA%2Fprojects, title: '2017 Quota Acknowledgement' }); return false;" id="btnSurvey1" type="button" value="Quota & Allocation Acknowledgement" />
```

Comment: This is actually the working code for the modal the one above doesn't work
    <input onclick="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({ url: 'https://share.philips.com/sites/STS020170908232517/quota/Lists/2017%20Quota%20Acknowledgement/NewForm.aspx', title: '2017 Quota Acknowledgement' }); return false;" id="btnSurvey1" type="button" value="Quota & Allocation Acknowledgement" />